# Can I load a Zip file to my app (previously downloaded)

Tags: zip, wit.ai

I downloaded the Zip file containing all the app data and now I want to load it back instead of the existing one.

Is it even possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes is it possible through the HTTP API but you'll have to code some scripts.

The easiest solution is to create a new Wit.ai app and import your zip file during the creation process.